# Is there a way to change variable during call?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

tensorflow2.0 has a format of class init and call
for example

```
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    return self.d2(x)

model = MyModel()
```

my question is that if I want to change the

```
> def call(self, x):
>     x = self.conv1(x)
>     x = self.flatten(x)
>     x = self.d1(x)
>     return self.d2(x,activation='relu')
```

this cause the error. 
if I want to change the attribute during some process 
how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the behavior of the forward pass depending on a condition,l you can just add a parameter to the `call` method.

From your example, it looks like you want to change the activation function of the last layer. Thus, you can just define the last layer with a linear activation function, and apply the desired activation function depending on a condition.

```py
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
    self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
    # note: no activation = linear activation
    self.d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    # Create two activation layers
    self.relu =  tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
    self.softmax = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()

  def call(self, x, condition):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    x = self.d2(x)
    # Change the activation depending on the condition
    if condition:
      tf.print("callign with activation=relu")
      x = self.relu(x)
    return self.softmax(x)

model = MyModel()

fake_input = tf.zeros((1, 28, 28, 1))

tf.print("condition false")
tf.print(model(fake_input, condition=False))
tf.print("condition true")
tf.print(model(fake_input, condition=True))
```